# Cardboard.SDK.VRModeEnabled fullscreen touch control

Tags: touch, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am able to have my app run in VR mode and all works well, I can view 360 degrees, gaze at menu options etc, all good.

I can also switch to fullscreen mode and for the most part, all good in that I can view 360 degrees, but I have to physically rotate the device as if in VR mode, there is no touch control to enable a user to swipe in all directions to view the 360 world.

Is there a way to achieve this?  Should I be disabling Cardboard an implementing a new camera?